# First HTTP request always slow

Tags: go

I have following code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func Get(url string, client *http.Client, header []string) (*http.Response, error) {
    start := time.Now()
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(header)/2; i++ {
        req.Header.Add(header[2*i], header[2*i+1])
    }
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    fmt.Println(time.Until(start))
    return resp, nil
}

func main() {
    header := []string{"accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"}

    cl := &http.Client{}
    url1 := "https://example1.com"
    url2 := "https://example2.com"
    url3 := "https://www.google.com/"

    resp, _ := Get(url1, cl, header)
    resp, _ = Get(url2, cl, header)
    resp, _ = Get(url3, cl, header)
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

The time of `resp, _ := Get(url1, cl, header)` is always slow
Regardless of `url1` change to https://example2.com or https://www.google.com/

like this

```
1 254.156959ms
2 34.183151ms
2 87.880252ms
```

Comment: It sounds like you might have slow DNS resolution. Do you see the same behavior if you use some other tool, such as curl, or even ping?

Comment: This didn't happen when I used python requests

Comment: first time get is slower than python requests.second time get is equal python request

Comment: dos this help ? https://blog.golang.org/http-tracing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a beautiful [article](https://revs.runtime-revolution.com/golang-dns-resolving-a56ed59981fe) on medium on resolving go's DNS issues. Shortly it refers to the [Name_Resolution](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#hdr-Name_Resolution)  of the `net` package documentation.

More info can be found in `src/net/lookup.go`, if you like to read [code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/296ddf2a936a30866303a64d49bc0e3e034730a8/src/net/lookup.go) (and comments).

TL/DR: go can use different dns resolvers, wich you can enable/or test with

```
GODEBUG=netdns=1 go run main.go
> go package net: hostLookupOrder(redis) = cgo
// osx/macosx case
GODEBUG=netdns=go+2 go run main.go
> go package net: GODEBUG setting forcing use of Go’s resolver go 
> package net: hostLookupOrder(redis) = files,dns
```